# Dynamically add sub menu items to tray icon context menu

Tags: electron

I have a tray icon with a context menu, it has several predefined items (js array of objects)

One of the options is defined as follows

```
      {
        id: "MyItem",
        label: "MyItem Label,
        submenu: []
      }
```

For some reason, when I populate the submenu with menu items, they don't appear in the tray icon context menu >>MyItem>>submenu (it remains empty), I do see the JS object being updated properly with the right values (
submenu>>items are populated with MenuItems)

I try to append them like this (but they are not reflected in the tray icon):

```
let MyItemElm = contextMenu.getMenuItemById("MyItem");
MyItemElm.submenu.items.push(new MenuItem(item1));
MyItemElm.submenu.items.push(new MenuItem(item2));
```

When I try to push the same item1/2 to the ROOT of the context menu it does work, like this:

```
contextMenu.insert(8, new MenuItem(item1))
contextMenu.insert(8, new MenuItem(item2))
```

Any ideas on what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by using the following:

```
let MyItemElm = contextMenu.getMenuItemById("MyItem");
MyItemElm.submenu.insert(0, new MenuItem(item));
```